# Add a table to a content control

Tags: .net, ms-word, openxml

[This tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197932%28v=office.12%29.aspx) suggests nesting tables in content controls but every time I'm trying to do this I get an error saying 'Word cannot turn off design mode because placeholder text in a content control contains invalid items'. I've tried both Rich Text and Plain Text content controls. Office version is 2012.

**How do I add a table to a content control?**

Comment: I've tested the tutorial with MS Word 2007 and it works. Make sure you add a rich text box content control to your word document and lable it. Furthermore the rich text box content control must contain a table with one row and three cells.

Comment: While dropping the tables/controls inside control turn off the "Design Mode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if design mode is turned off. However I'm still not satisfied, because Word automatically adds an empty paragraph after every table.

Comment: Deleting the paragraph is easy but not intuitive.  You can either select the paragraph and then select out of the bottom of the control and then press delete from within Word (this is super easy to do); or you can open the document package in Visual Studio, find the document.xml file, and just remove the line of text that is the paragraph.  

The problem is getting the paragraph back when you need it!

Answer (score 0):

From my own experimentation, and reading the VBA documentation. There are only a limited set of supported use-cases for where the start and end of a content control can appear in a document. With a related constant, [`control.Level`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcontentcontrollevel) so you can tell them apart.

- `wdContentControlLevelInline` - Inline within a single paragraph.
- `wdContentControlLevelParagraph` - Some number of whole paragraphs.
- `wdContentControlLevelRow` - Linked to one row of a table.
- `wdContentControlLevelCell` - A single table cell.

There seems to be a 5th option. If you create a table first, then select it and add the control. No extra blank lines are inserted. However if you remove the table, the control will also be removed. If you use VBA to examine the `Range.Start` & `Range.End` of the table and control, you will see that the table encapsulates the Paragraph control.

It doesn't seem possible to paste an excel table into an existing content control, without creating extra paragraphs.

If you do insert a table into an existing control, it will first be converted to `LevelParagraph`. With a leading and trailing blank line. While you can remove the leading paragraph, word won't allow you to remove the trailing paragraph.

However you could selected it and change the font effect to "Hidden". At least then it won't be printed.

Or you must delete both the content control & table, then recreate them.